# Is there any other way to sign the Android app bundle without using "Android/xamarian signing task" in Azure Devops

Tags: android, kotlin, azure-pipelines, build.gradle, android-app-signing

> When I use the Android signing task in my azure devops build pipeline, It is signing the prod app bundle but it's not signing the dev app bundle because of the signing config code lines(in build.gradle file) related to Dev and also the Dev keystore file upload in the repo.
>  I think these are making pipeline unable to use the release/production keystore file present in azure pipeline secure files. Ultimately, this is resulting in failing the pipeline.
> **I tried to comment the signing config code lines in build.gradle but it's still not signing the app bundle.
> Is there any other way to sign the app bundle?** 
>  I got struck on this, can anyone please answer this question or atleast start a discussion so that I might get a solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could sign app bundle in the  **Build** Pipeline instead of  from the Azure **Release** pipeline through `jarsigner`.

You could follow the command line to sign Android app Bundle:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore $(KeyStoreFile.secureFilePath) -storepass $(KeyPassword) -keypass $(KeyPassword) $(system.defaultworkingdirectory)/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/*.aab $(KeyAliass)
```

`KeyPassword` and `KeyAlias` are pipeline variables and `KeyStoreFile` is available by using Secure File task.